# how to rollback changes done in database using java program

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have written a java program to update the records in database. I don't want to commit the changes immediately. I need to check whether the rows are updated properly or not. After that i wanted to commit otherwise the changes need to be rollbacked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setAutoCommit(false)`:

```
Connection con = null;
try {
    con = DBConnection.getConnection();

    //set auto commit to false
    con.setAutoCommit(false);

    EmployeeJDBCInsertExample.insertEmployeeData(con, 1, "Pankaj");

    EmployeeJDBCInsertExample.insertAddressData(con, 1, "Albany Dr", "San Jose", "USA");

    // Here do your checks
    if (everything ok) {
         con.commit();
    } else {
         con.rollback();
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    try {
        // something goes wrong, rollback the transaction
        con.rollback();
        System.out.println("JDBC Transaction rolled back successfully");
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println("SQLException in rollback"+e.getMessage());
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (con != null)
            con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: From the code i dont get any errors. After updating i have to check the records in database and need to do some opertaions. Later if the changes are not correct then i need to rollback.@fluminis

Comment: I updated my example. You just need to do your verifications and decide if you want do commit or rollback the changes.